# Operations on tensor segments in 2nd dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the best way to perform an operation on segments of a tensor in a dimension other than the first? For example, a simple sum of segments in the 2nd dimension:

Given:

```
x11 x12 x13 x14 x15
...
xN1 xN2 xN3 xN4 xN5
```

I would like to obtain:

```
x11+x12 x13+x14+x15
...
xN1+xN2 xN3+xN4+xN5
```

Optimally, I would like to achieve behavior similar to `unsorted_segment_sum` in other dimensions (i.e. the segment ids don't have to be sorted and cover all values):

```
x11+x15 x12+x14
...
xN1+xN5 xN2+xN4
```

Assuming that the first dimension is usually used to represent a batch, it would be quite useful to perform operations on segments of data samples.

Currently, the only alternative that I see is to extract a slice of a tensor for each segment and perform a reduction operation on each slice. Is there a better alternative (i.e. one that would lead to better performance)?

Comment: Could you not just transpose the matrix to work on columns (now rows on transposed matrix) with `tf.unsorted_segment_sum()`?

Comment: Isn't transpose op expensive in TF?

Comment: Yes it is, but for now I don't see other options, because you can only work on the first dimension with indices.

Comment: What did you do finally ?