# How to do pairwise addition in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am new in tensorflow so this might be an easy question, but it is really stuck me
I am tring to implement this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BynEQyOSGRoSbG5TMTdXaWczY00/view) by keras, background is tensorflow
In first stage of training, he used `softmax_pair`
if we got this output from last fc
vertical is batch size and this is NoneType

```
x11 x12 x13 x14...   
x21 x22 x23 x24...   
x31 x32 x33 x34...
...
```

and we do exponential, so we have

```
e11 e12 e13 e14...   
e21 e22 e23 e24...   
e31 e32 e33 e34...
...
```

and then, I am stuck here

```
e11/(e11+e12) e12/(e11+e12) e13/(e13+e14) e14/(e13+e14)...
e21/(e21+e22) e22/(e21+e22) e23/(e23+e24) e24/(e23+e24)...
e31/(e31+e32) e32/(e31+e32) e33/(e33+e34) e34/(e33+e34)...
...
```

I don't know how to do pairwise addition
`tf.transpose` and `tf.segment_sum` might be great
but after research I found transpose is expensive
further more, after `tf.segment_sum` I only have half size of tensor,
I don't know how to double it
oh and I am thinking how to produce segment_ids

so how can I do this calculate?
Thanks!!

----------update
The part I talked in paper is Fig.3
The fc output is P2c-1 and P2c, which is mean possibility of class c appear or not appear in the image
c=1,2,3...num of class

### Is transpose not expensive? sometimes I see this,e.g. [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505597/operations-on-tensor-segments-in-2nd-dimension) ,perhaps I misunderstood this?

The tensorflow docs for `tf.transpose` state that unlike numpy tensorflow returns a new tensor -> memory.

Comment: What part of the paper do you talk about? Is the number of columns always `4`? Why do you think transpose is expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `X` is your tensor of size `R x C`:

```
_, C = X.get_shape()
X_split = tf.split(1, C/2, X)
Y_split = [tf.nn.softmax(slice) for slice in X_split]
Y = tf.concat(1, Y_split)
```

`C` will be the number of colums, `X_split` will be a list of subtensors, each having a two columns, `Y_split` will calculate regular softmax for each of the tensors, `Y` will join the results of softmaxes.

Comment: Thanks!! I google it for few days, such a elegant code, about your question I update the post please see it